# How do I submit a form inside a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

How can I create a program with C# to submit the form(in the web browser CONTROL in windows Apps)automaticlly ?

Answer (score 34):

The [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) has a [Document property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx), which returns an [HtmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx).  The HtmlDocument has [several members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument_members.aspx) you can use to traverse and manipulate the DOM.

Once you've used these methods to find the form, you can use [InvokeMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.invokemember.aspx) to call the form's submit method.

If you know the page has a single form:

```
foreach (HtmlElement form in webBrowser1.Document.Forms)
    form.InvokeMember("submit");
```

If you know the ID of the form you would like to submit:

```
HtmlElement form = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("FormID");
if (form != null)
    form.InvokeMember("submit");
```

Comment: before submitting, you can fill out the form like this-- webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("PRICE1").SetAttribute("value", "100");

Comment: Not only can, but **must**: Without first filling out required/mandatory input fields, the submission is bound to fail or simply produced undesired/unexpected results. Note that the first parameter in `SetAttribute()` is always **"Value"** (with the quotes). +1

Comment: is there a way to find out what happened after submit? like get the response ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the page has a single form or you want the first form:

```
HTMLDocument doc = webBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;    
HTMLFormElement form = doc.all.OfType<HTMLFormElement>().First();
form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("form_submit").InvokeMember("click");
```